# How to interact with fzf on remote machine with tramp mode

Tags: tramp, navigation, fzf

Suppose, we work on a remote server with project files. The project files are located in directory:

```
/ssh:server:/home/user/onetouch/lib
```

I created the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /home/user/onetouch/lib -type f \                    # search files in project directory 
      -name '*.pm' ! -name '*~' \                         # only .pm files, no backup
      -not -path ".git/*" \                               # no .git directory
      -not -path "*/Modules/*" -not -path "*/Base/*" \    # no /Modules and /Base --- these are submodules
      | fzf                                               # we don't need them
```

How can I interact with remote fzf in Emacs, so I could quickly open the files?

I checked fzf-mode and counsel-fzf, but couldn't make them work via tramp?

Comment: Did you try using fzf from within Emacs with bling/fzf.el (from GitHub)?   I'm not sure if it works within tramp but it might.